# Kafka: Does Confluent’s HDFS connector support Snappy compression?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I don't see any configurations for compression on the HDFS connector docs https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-hdfs/docs/configuration_options.html.

- Does it support compression?
- If yes, what do I need to add in the properties file?

Answer (score 1):

Snappy compression was recently added to the HDFS Connector for Avro. To enable it you'll need to set the property `avro.codec` to `snappy`.

With Parquet it's been available since the beginning and it is the codec used when exporting parquet files.

Here's the PR that added it for Avro:

https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-hdfs/pull/255

This config property will become available in the forthcoming 4.1.0 release of the connector. That's also when the link to the docs will be updated to reflect this addition.