# avro.codec not working in hdfs sink connector for snappy compression

Tags: apache-kafka, hdfs, avro, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I'm using confluent hdfs sink connector, Im inserting the data in avro format.

I want the data to be compressed using snappy compression.

[Kafka: Does Confluent’s HDFS connector support Snappy compression?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49139574/10477963)
I used the solution mentioned in the thread above

I added the config

avro.codec=snappy

However, it didnt work for me
As in , the files created were not compressed with snappy compression.
Usually when I run spark jobs, my files are appended with the .snappy file extension
However, in this case, I don't see that happening. I'm assuming that my files are not getting compressed with snappy.

Is there any other configuration I'm missing out on?

Comment: What do you mean "didn't work"? What are you expecting to see when you set that property?

Comment: As in , the files created were not compressed with snappy compression.
Usually when I run spark jobs, my files are appended with the .snappy file extension
However, in this case, I don't see that happening. I'm assuming that my files are not getting compressed with snappy.

Comment: File extensions don't mean anything, and Kafka Connect AvroFormat always suffixes with avro file extension. I forget how I checked, but I think you need to use a hex viewer to inspect the data to see it says "snappy" in the Avro header (I use S3 Connect, not HDFS, but I think the Avro file writer is the same)... If you write the same data without the codec, you'll likely see larger sized files as well

Comment: Alright! 
Thanks a lot! 

I used ,


[hadoop jar /path/to/avro-tools.jar getmeta FILE_LOCATION_ON_HDFS --key 'avro.codec' ]

to check the compression on my file and it shows snappy! 

It was a mistake from my end, it had worked perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Avro tools available, you can use it to inspect the file

```
$ java -jar avro-tools-1.8.1.jar getmeta kafka-connect-file.avro

avro.schema {"type":"record","name":"...
avro.codec  snappy
```

Also with a hex editor

```
$ cat kafka-connect-file.avro | xxd | grep -B1 snappy

00001c00: 656e 7422 7d14 6176 726f 2e63 6f64 6563  ent"}.avro.codec
00001c10: 0c73 6e61 7070 7900 9fd1 5fb0 2a3a 45ba  .snappy..._.*:E.
```

---

To convert the file to a non-snappy Avro file, you can use `recodec` of Avro tools.

```
$ java -jar avro-tools-1.8.1.jar recodec kafka-connect-file.avro > non-snappy.avro
$ ls -l *.avro  # Should see slight difference in Avro file sizes
```